# Get the index of the first element in an array that meets the specified condition

Tags: find, path-finding, dolphindb, hit, findfirst

For example, I have an array `data = 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1`. I want to get the index of the first non-zero element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `ifirstHit`. For example:

```
data = 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
ifirstHit(ne, data, 0)
```

Output: 6

Answer (score 1):

## Find first 1

```
data.find(1)
```

## Find first non-zero element

```
data.find(data[data != 0].first())
```